# Signing in to Pokemon Go with Google - only gives sign UP option not sign IN

Tags: pokemon-go

When I open the app, it normally just loads the game. Now, it is taking me to the google SIGN UP page, and does not give me the option to simply SIGN IN to my account. I do not want to make a new account, just sign into the one I already have. (I have not changed phones, this just started happening out of the blue.) Sorry if this is a silly question, but I am a bit lost here!

Comment: There was an update not too long ago, usually the log-in features disappear while the game is in maintenance-mode.  Gotta wait this one out a bit it seems. :(\